# Why is my eclipse setup not working with the maven plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, elasticsearch, tridion

I'm fairly new to Elastic Search and am trying to work on a project which used the Maven plugin and SI4T library - https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T

For some reason when I open my project, a lot of libraries are missing!

Literally all the packages are missing class files - anyone any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not missing, they are right there. I suspect that because your screenshot says "Source not found" you assume they are not present. That thing you double clicked is the class file.

Have you tried using them?

You can make maven download the sources as well. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven and check the boxes for "Download Artifact Sources".

EDIT: Some explanation!

Maven resolves the dependencies that you need. But in order to use those dependencies, you don't need the source code, only the compiled class files. When opening class files, eclipse attempts to look for the source code that these classes originated from, since the source code is way more readable than the compiled bytecode.